# does jOOQ support querying on local results?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Say you have fetched some data from the database:

```
Record r = <DSLContext>.select()...fetch();
```

Does jOOQ support further local querying on the result?

```
<DSLContext>.select(...).from(r).where(...)...fetch();
```

Sometimes, it makes sense to locally query results, based on earlier queries on the database.

I could not find anything useful in the documentation, so I guess the answer is no. However, I am asking it here anyway, for certainty and possibly initiating some thoughts or discussions about this feature (although this isn't the purpose of SO).

Comment: http://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql mentions that we can stream the result set in Java 8 and filter it.

Comment: I guess the question is: does jOOQ support the streaming/filtering (Java 8, Guava, ...) based on actual SQL queries? The input is a table, the output is a table and the language is SQL. I would like to have the implementation of the actual filtering left out, and solely rely on SQL.

Comment: @JefJedrison: The examples shown on http://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql will be transforming the result in Java memory, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want another round trip to the database, then yes, you can create a new [`org.jooq.Table`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html) from a [`org.jooq.Result`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html) using [`DSL.table(Result)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Result-):

```java
select(...)
.from(DSL.table(result))
.where(...)
.fetch();
```

This will generate a table using a SQL [`VALUES(...)` constructor](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#values-org.jooq.RowN...-) if your database supports that, or a derived table with `UNION ALL`, otherwise:

```sql
-- If database supports VALUES()
SELECT ...
FROM (VALUES (1, 'a'),
             (2, 'b'),
             (3, 'c')) t(column1, column2)
WHERE ...

-- Otherwise
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT 1 column1, 'a' column2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2        , 'b'         UNION ALL
      SELECT 3        , 'c') t
WHERE ...

-- actual SQL may vary, of course
```

An alternative version that takes `Record` instead of `Result` is on the roadmap for jOOQ 3.6: [#4009](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4009). In the meantime, you'll have to either use the original `Result` reference, or create a new instance using one of the [`DSLContext.newResult(...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newResult-org.jooq.Field...-) methods.